# What is happening in this function?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was looking for a method to display the contents of Binary search tree in inorder method. I found this method which seems quite popular but I cannot understand how is this recursion working. How will the code ever reach cout? Also root node is being passed into the function when called by the main function. EDIT: This is considering that "root!=NULL".

```
    void display(struct tree *p)
{
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        display(p->left);
        cout<<p->data;
        display(p->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: The function void display(struct tree *p) will be pushed on to the stack frame till p !=NULL always with different argument. And when p will reach to NULL then unwinding will happen that will be cause cout to print the result

Comment: @Swapnil and exactly how will p reach NULL within a given call of the function?

Comment: @PeteKirkham When p dosen't have any leaf node on its left. Correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @Swapnil And how will we able to get back to the parent node of the leaf which had p->left=NULL?

Comment: That function is broken - the `while` should be `if`. Other than that, recursive functions work exactly like all other functions.

Comment: C++ code should use  nullptr  (not NULL)

Comment: Since you haven't posted it but used the word 'tree'; we're all assuming that `tree->left->right != tree` (ie it really is a tree rather than a list) otherwise you've another infinate loop there

Answer (score 6):

First of all, instead of `while(p!=NULL)` you should use `if (p != null)`. Otherwise, you get an infinite loop in case the root node is not null.

It first displays the left subtree calling recursively `display(p->left)`. After that it displays the node itself (`cout<data`) and finally the right subtree calling recursively `display(p->right)`.

Suppose you have the following tree:

```
      4
  2       6
1  3     5
```

A call to display(root), results in the following function calls:

```
display(4)
  display(2)
    display(1)
      display(null)
      cout 1
      display(null)
    cout 2
    display(3)
      display(null)
      cout 3
      display(null)
  cout 4
  display(6)
    display(5)
      display(null)
      cout 5
      display(null)
    cout 6
    display(null)
```

When the function is called for node "1", it first displays the left subtree by calling `display(p->left)`.
That function notices `p==null` returning therefore directly.
So control returns to display(1).
The next statement is `cout << 1`.
After that, it displays the right subtree by calling `display(p->right)`.
That function notices `p==null` returning therefore directly.
So again, control returns to display(1).
At this point, display(1) has terminated and control returns to the function that called display(1), being display(2).
It finished its call to `display(p->left)` (being "1") and therefore executes it next statement, which is `cout << 2`.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to me mention this is only considering root!=NULL

Comment: Also `cout<<p->data;` -> `cout << p->data << endl;`, otherwise your output will probably be unreadable.

Comment: What happens when 1 is printed, which line of code is responsible for it to move towards the parent node(in this case 2).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the code will reach `cout` is that function `display` will not recurse all the time.

**Once the parameter passed to `display` become `NULL`**,that is,you have reached the leaf node of that tree, the recursion will start to trace back,the stack will start unwinding.Finally the control will return to the origin call of `display`.And it begins to execute the `cout`.

And that's why the judgement `while(p!=NULL)` is indispensable.